# Ubuntu 18.04 with GUI for Azure

Tags: azure

Does it exist Ubuntu 18.04 with GUI for Azure or only Server edition?

Comment: and if not this will https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/templates/ubuntu-desktop-gnome/

Comment: It's good, thanks, but I mean does it exist image with already installed GUI. Anyway I can install it myself.